# merging pandas dataframes with left join causes 'cannot convert float NaN to integer' error

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I have two related dataframes Students (student_id, name, surname) and CourseEnrollments (course_id, student_id).

```
Students
student_id | name | surname
11           aa     aaa
22           bb     bbb
33           cc     ddd

CourseEnrollments
course_id | student_id
44           11     
55           22     
66           11
```

I want to merge these two datasets and preserve all enrollments while keeping only students with some enrollments in the final dataset:

```
StudentCourseEnrollments

course_id | student_id | name | surname
44          11           aa     aaa
55          22           bb     bbb
66          11           aa     aaa
```

However, when I do a `left` join, I receive `'cannot convert float NaN to integer'` error for some reason. `Inner` or `right` joins do not throw an exception. I believe `inner` join should also work in my case, is that right? However, I am also curious why I receive this error with `left` join. Below is my code:

```
Students = Students.dropna(subset=['student_id'])
CourseEnrollments = CourseEnrollments.dropna(subset=['student_id'])
CourseEnrollments.merge(Students, how='left', left_on='student_id', right_on='student_id'
```

Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Can you show the dataframes' `.dtypes`?